# $MyInvocation in a runspace Thread

Tags: multithreading, powershell

A script (foo.ps1) creates a thread, and that thread creates more threads. Foo's thread is my control thread, and it creates one or more worker threads. The worker threads run a script block. The script block calls functions from a library-script. The library script has a configuration file.

The script block loads the library-script by dot-sourcing it.

```
$block = {
  Param($library_script)
  . $library_script
  ...stuff...
}
```

When the script loads, the first thing it does is find its configuration file, which is in the script's directory. The code for that looks like...

```
## Global variables and enumerations
$script:self_location = $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$script:configuration_file_location = "{0}.config" -f $script:self_location
```

My problem is `$MyInvocation` doesn't appear to exist. As result, the library script can't find it's configuration file.

I'm running Powershell 5.1 on Windows 10. The control thread was made in a runspace. The worker threads are made in a runspace pool.

Does anyone know the rules around the automatic `$MyInvocation` variable in runspace threads?

Create a file `foo.ps1` and add the following to it:

```
Write-Output '[1] Executed in-scope'
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

Write-Output '[2] Executed in-thread'
$p1 = [PowerShell]::Create()
$p1.AddScript({ $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path }) | Out-Null
$p1.Invoke()
$p1.Dispose()

Write-Output '[3] Executed in-thread in-thread'
$t = {
$p = [PowerShell]::Create()
$p.AddScript({ $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path }) | Out-Null
$p.Invoke()
}

$p2 = [PowerShell]::Create()
$p2.AddScript( $t ) | Out-Null
$p2.Invoke()
$p2.Dispose()
```

Run it. You should see something like the following...

```
[1] Executed in-scope
C:\Users\deezNuts\development\comcast\sandbox\thing.ps1
[2] Executed in-thread
[3] Executed in-thread in-thread
```

And, I think I just answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I see variable in thread.

```
$rsp = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 2, $iss, $Host)
$rsp.ApartmentState = "STA"
$rsp.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
$rsp.Open()

$p = [PowerShell]::Create()
$p.RunspacePool = $rsp
$p.AddScript({ write-host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path })
$h = $p.BeginInvoke()
$p.EndInvoke($h)

$p.Dispose()
$rsp.Dispose()
```

What are you doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that $MyInvocation variable is supported in a background job

```
Start-Job -Name Test -ScriptBlock {Get-Variable}
Receive-Job Test
```

Can you pass the path as a parameter ?

Comment: No, I don't see `$MyInvocation` when checking from a Powershell job, but I'm using runspaces (not a Powershell job). It works a bit different.